# A simple Javascript function not working (converting Fahrenheit to Celsius)

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to make it so when you click the button "Click Here!" the following sentence appears: "The temperature is 25 Celsius." Can somebody tell my why my code failes to work and how can I fix it?
Here is my Code:

```
<p id="demo">This is my first paragraph</p>

<button type="button" onclick="toCelsius(fahrenheit)">Click Here!</button>

<script>
    function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
        return (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The temperature is " +  toCelsius(77) + " Celsius";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It fails because the `return` statement exits the function - it never reaches the next line where you set the innerHTML.

Comment: point out the cause of "why does my code failed", some error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed the return statement too early (the return statement always ends the execution of the function, so the part that displayed the temperature wasn't running.)

Replace `return` with `var c=` and replace `toCelsius(77)` with `c` below it.

Also, your button event handler says `toCelsius(fahrenheit)`; `fahrenheit` is not defined. If you add an `<input id='fahrenheit' placeholder='temperature' />` on your page, you can change the button's event handler to `toCelsius(document.getElementById('fahrenheit').value)`.

:) Just like that, you have a calculator!

Example:

```
 <p id="demo">This is my first paragraph</p>

<input id='fahrenheit' placeholder='temperature' />
<button type="button" onclick="toCelsius(document.getElementById('fahrenheit').value)">Click Here!</button>

<script>
     function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
     var celsius (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The temperature is " +
          celsius + " Celsius";
     }
</script>
```

Comment: He also has too many recursions, calling same function inside it `toCelsius(77)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<script>
    function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
        return (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);
    };

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The temperature is " +  toCelsius(77) + " Celsius";

</script>
```

Your code doesn't work because, You have a return statement **before** an assignment to a innerHtml property.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
<script>
function toCelsius(fahrenheit) {
    return (5/9) * (fahrenheit-32);
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The temperature is " +  toCelsius(77) + " Celsius";
</script>
```